# Can I change the port of an embedded Tomcat at runtime?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I'm using Tomcat embedded in my Java 8 application. I tried to switch the port at runtime like this:

```
 Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(18080);

    Timer timer =new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tomcat.setPort(18181);
        }
    },240000L);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The wepapp responds still only to port 18080 after the timer delay was reached.

Is switching even possible at runtime? How can i do it?

EDIT:

Using Tomcat embedded 8.0.3 on JDK 1.8.0b129

I'd like to avoid to restart the server because the startup process takes a long time.

Comment: Why do you need to change the port?

Comment: Another server app has to serve on this port as seamlessly as possible, so it's about avoiding any downtime.

Comment: @thejeed ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @DavidWelch Unfortunately, I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

you should try restart server:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tomcat.stop();
            tomcat.setPort(18181);
            tomcat.start();
            tomcat.getServer().await();
        }
},240000L);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the startup process is very expensive, so i want to avoid to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call its default http connectors destroy method, but I dont know if that is possible in Tomcat 8.

Comment: Your method almost works. I'm calling `stop()` and `destroy()` on the connector and then, i instantiate a new one and assign it to the server instance. Unfortunately, no request can be handled after that - i'm getting NPEs from Coyote.postParseRequest().